# Reactjs let list component watch context individually

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

is there any performance impact or other disadvantage when we let each component to watch their own state

<s>For example [codepen](https://codepen.io/wiryono/pen/JjLoNNN)</s>

[Fixed here](https://codepen.io/wiryono/pen/eYPxVYp)

```js
const DataContext = React.createContext();

const DataReducer = function (state, action) {
  switch (action.method) {
    case "add":
      state[action.id] = action.params;
      break;
    case "delete":
      delete state[action.id];
      break;
    default:
  }
  return { ...state };
};

const DataContextProvider = function (props) {
  let [data, setData] = React.useReducer(DataReducer, {});
  let [filter, setFilter] = React.useState(null);

  let value = {
    data: data,
    setData: setData,
    filter: filter,
    setFilter: setFilter
  };

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</DataContext.Provider>
  );
};

const DelayInput = function (props) {
  let [timer, setTimer] = React.useState(null);

  let delay = props.delay ? props.delay : 1000;

  let delayChange = (e) => {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      setTimer(null);
    }
    setTimer(
      setTimeout(() => {
        props.onChange(e.target);
      }, delay)
    );
  };

  return (
    <input
      className="input"
      type="text"
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      defaultValue={props.value}
      onChange={delayChange}
      name={props.name}
    />
  );
};

const Tool = function (props) {
  let { setData, setFilter } = React.useContext(DataContext);

  let handleChange = ((e) => {
    setFilter(e.value);
  });

  let handleClick = () => {
    setData({
      method: "add",
      id: new Date().getTime(),
      params: {
        x: Math.random(),
        y: Math.random(),
        last: new Date().getTime()
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button className="button" onClick={handleClick}>
        Add
      </button>
      <DelayInput
        name="filter"
        placeholder="Filter"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const Row = function (props) {
  let { data, filter, setData } = React.useContext(DataContext);

  let handleClick = (() => {
    setData({
      method: "delete",
      id: props.id
    });
  });

  return React.useMemo(() => {
    if (filter && !props.id.toString().includes(filter)) {
      return null;
    }
    
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{props.id}</td>
        <td>{data[props.id].x}</td>
        <td>{data[props.id].y}</td>
        <td>{data[props.id].last}</td>
        <td>
          <button className="button is-narrow" onClick={handleClick}>
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }, [filter, data[props.id]]);
};

const TableContent = function (props) {
  let { data } = React.useContext(DataContext);

  return React.useMemo(() => {
    return Object.keys(data).map((i) => {
      return <Row key={i} id={i} />;
    });
  }, [Object.keys(data)]);
};

const Container = function (props) {
  return (
    <DataContextProvider>
      <Tool />
      <table className="table is-bordered is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>X</th>
            <th>Y</th>
            <th>Last Update</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <TableContent />
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </DataContextProvider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<Container />);
```

My understanding that with this we can make sure that this one component only care about his state, something like observer pattern and separation of responsibility.

The state inside context is the data
The component become observer of the chosen state and change accordingly to it, in my example is **Row** component

Row component also observe **filter** value, if the value in the filter change and itself doesn't match the filter then it will hide itself.

And since the row watch his own state, we can freely memoize the component

Is there any disadvantage for this kind of approach ?

Answer (score 0):

So when you're using context like this, each child component that uses the context will rerender **whenever any part of the data changes**.

This means that even if `data[props.id]` doesn't change, it will rerender if any part of `data` changes.

I'd recommend using Redux instead. I actually just used it for myself the other day for the first time, and it was easier than I expected. Unlike `useContext`, it allows you to subscribe to a tiny slice of the state, and only rerender when the state you depend on changes. See [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) for details.

Comment: From my testing ( added console.log ). useMemo part is always useless in the TableContent since the data always change on add, filter, and delete.

What i think is success is on Add it only render the new data, on Filter always render because each row watch their own state, on Delete TableContent rerender but not all the Row

Comment: I haven't grasp redux advantage, since I use react from v17 when context stuff is available.

Answer (score 0):

If Context API is used properly, then only those components consuming Context will re-render when this changes. I recommend you take a look at [react-context-slices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-slices), it's a library that uses React Context in an optimal way and allows you to define slices of Context easily and with 0 boilerplate. In this manner, only the components fetching each slice of Context will update when its value change. You do it like this:

```
// slices.js
import getHookAndProviderFromSlices from "react-context-slices"
export const {useSlice, Provider} = getHookAndProviderFromSlices({
  count: {initialArg: 0},
  // rest of slices of Context you want to define
})
```

```
// app.js
import {useSlice} from "./slices"
const App = () => {
  const [count, useCount] = useSlice("count")
  return <>
    <button onClick={() => setCount(c => c + 1)}>+</button>{count}
  </>
}
```

Hope this helps anyone planning to use Context.

Answer (score 0):

Hi after tweaking it this is how I fix it

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/wiryono/pen/eYPxVYp)

```
For submit purpose
```

By creating an additional state that hold the active ( selected item )

On update I have to update both form and this state.

Currently doesn't have any problem, thought it feel a bit like a hack...